# Default location when browsing components

Tags: schema, 2013-sp1, component

When you hit the 'Browse' button on a component link within the schema fields on a structure group, a page or a component, is there a way to set a default folder location? This would save the editors some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Harald,

Sadly there is no default folder location that you can set.

But, as a workaround what I do is create a "Shortcuts" folder at the root level (right under building blocks) and create virtual folders to the commonly used folders for the editors

That way when the hit browse to add a component link they can reduce the number of clicks needed to reach the final folder containing the component:

[image]

Comment: Nice, you can do the same with Bundles to create shortcuts to other locations or even other Bundles.

Comment: @Alvin, since Bundles are VirtualFolders internally what would be more efficient in terms of performance, creating a VirtualFolder or a Bundle?

Comment: Bundles store the list of items in their XML, so sure they might be a bit faster. But they're also a manual selection of items that won't get automatic updates. I tend to suggest virtual folders for gathering items with the same Schema (e.g. "all Articles") and Bundles for manually curated lists or to help with a project (e.g. "stuff I'm working on for the next release").

Answer (score 4):

You can set the default location in CME. It is an out of the box feature, please look at the screenshot below. Once you set a start location, the next time you open the CME, you will directly come to this location without any clicks! Also I want to suggest careful use of virtual folders since it executes a search query everytime you click on the folder and is primarily meant for saved searches.

[image]